# How to determine colloborative (shared) mailboxes in google workspace using api

Tags: google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

I am looking for a way to determine if a  group is a colloborative mailbox using api/sdk. The existing properties returned in groups list does not seem to have anything like this. Can someone please advise?